# Uploaded to GCS through FirebaseSDK, but not reflected as a Class A operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, cost-management

I uploaded an object to GCS through FirebaseSDK, but when I look at the rates on the GCP side, it is not reflected as the number of Class A operations.

The bucket information is set as default bucket if us multi-region, standard class, Firebase side.

What I would like to do is to optimize the class of the bucket in GCS.
By changing the bucket class, not only the storage fee, but also the fee for class A and class B operations will change, but we are not sure how many requests are currently being made.

Looking at the CloudStorage fees from Firebase's fee structure (https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=ja), it says "The default bucket is listed as App Engine usage fees." so is it encapsulated in a fee item (SKUID) somewhere?

I searched by

- https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=en
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more?hl=en